# How to delete network acl using terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-vpc

I have created vpc and network acl using terraform. I am storing terraform state inside s3 buckets. While destroying environment I am facing the issue at refresh level for network acl.
Following are the error logs:

```
aws_network_acl_rule.allow_egress_icmp_test: Refreshing state... (ID: nacl-3823017959)

    Error: Error refreshing state: 2 error(s) occurred:

* aws_network_acl_rule.allow_ingress_icmp_test: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_network_acl_rule.allow_ingress_icmp_test: aws_network_acl_rule.allow_ingress_icmp_test: Error Finding Network Acl Rule 300: InvalidNetworkAclID.NotFound: The networkAcl ID 'acl-0659a5ff4ef450c40' does not exist
status code: 400, request id: 2b7047fa-aae6-4ad5-9788-e0c7b3b46eac
* aws_network_acl_rule.allow_egress_icmp_test: 1 error(s) occurred:
```

Comment: Terraform indicates that your network acl does not exist anymore. 
Do you delete it manually ? Or maybe start to destroy and stop terraform command ?

Comment: If you deleted it manyally use: terraform state rm aws_network_acl_rule.allow_ingress_icmp_test. Also,  you might be deleting the resource in two different places.